# Exploratory phone call turned into job offer. I like my job, should I ask my company to match?

Tags: job-offer

A while ago, a recruiter on LinkedIn reached out to me and we discussed a position. I interviewed and it looks like they are making an offer.

I'm not necessarily in a rush to leave my company, but the offer is very good. But I like the company culture, the people, the commute, everything (well, my job itself isn't as great as it could be but I think there's a path forward to improve that.) If I was being paid this amount at my current company then I would outright decline the offer.

Most advice I've seen is "don't ask for a counter offer" but that seems to be geared towards people who are actively looking to leave a job. Does that advice apply in this situation? I'd love to stay at my job but this offer is very enticing.

Comment: Any request for more money comes with the implication that you might leave if you don't get it. Are you prepared to do so?

Comment: Bringing it up with your current company <=> Be ready to leave. Do NOT do it unless you are ready to leave, else it will probably cost you more than you expect

Comment: @SethR yes: the new job role is similar to what I'm trying to get into with my current company.

Comment: Depends a bit how much you are currently making as compared to the "market'. If you are significantly underpaid at the moment, that would make it (in my opinion) sufficiently different enough from the duplicate answer to re-open

Comment: Don't. Negociate a raise, but do not bring this up as it will raise awareness that you are looking elsewhere. This will stress your current employer which will look for a replacement as well.